# Error:(52, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'сompile()' in using Quickblox API

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, quickblox

I tried to use Quickblox API in my program by adding online maven dependencies.
I'm using Android Studio.
When I tried to build my program, it shows the following error:

> Error:(52, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: `сompile()`
>     Possible causes:
>
> The project 'Nanny Watch' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
>     Open Gradle wrapper file
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
>     Apply Gradle plugin

Here is the build.gradle(Project:NannyWatch2) file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {

        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And here is the build.gradle(Module:App) file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.nannywatch"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    def qbSdkVersion = '2.5'

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'net.schmizz:sshj:0.10.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile('vc908.stickers:stickerfactory:0.2.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'  

// I tried using jar compile, but the method QBPushNotifications cannot be resolved
// Therefore I tried to use the online repository

//    compile files('src/main/java/com/example/user/nannywatch/jars/quickblox-android-sdk-chat-2.4.jar')
//    compile files('src/main/java/com/example/user/nannywatch/jars/quickblox-android-sdk-content-2.4.jar')
//    compile files('src/main/java/com/example/user/nannywatch/jars/quickblox-android-sdk-core-2.4.jar')
//    compile files('src/main/java/com/example/user/nannywatch/jars/quickblox-android-sdk-customobjects-2.4.jar')
//    compile files('src/main/java/com/example/user/nannywatch/jars/quickblox-android-sdk-location-2.4.jar')
//    compile files('src/main/java/com/example/user/nannywatch/jars/quickblox-android-sdk-messages-2.4.jar')
//    compile files('src/main/java/com/example/user/nannywatch/jars/quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc-2.4.jar')  

    сompile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:$qbSdkVersion@aar"
    сompile ("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:$qbSdkVersion@aar"){
        transitive=true
    }
    сompile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:$qbSdkVersion@aar"
    сompile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-messages:$qbSdkVersion@aar"
    сompile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-customobjects:$qbSdkVersion@aar"
    сompile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-location:$qbSdkVersion@aar"
    сompile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc:$qbSdkVersion@aar"
}
```

There is also this warning: 'dependencies' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure)'
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hk4cD.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a very strange "bug". When you copied and pasted the Gradle lines from [Quickblox](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases), you copied a wrong ASCII code of the letter "c" in the word compile and Gradle would not recognize the word "compile".

- the ASCII code of "c" copied from Quickblox site is 209 129
- the ASCII code of "c" is 99

You can try it yourself using this link: [string to ASCII](http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/ascii/)

- regular letter → c
- Quickblox letter → с

Convert each letter and you will get a different ASCII code.

So the solution is very simple, delete the letter c and write it yourself :)

Comment: This solved the problem. Gosh, it seems like a April fool's day joke or something, but it actually wastes a lot of time. I am going to report this on their GitHub issue tracker now.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you. I wasted hours on this.

Comment: Thanks, I can't think of a logical sequence of events that lead you to find this solution... I am curious, how did you come up with it?

Comment: @Emer The mind of desperate developer is very complex :P

Comment: I was able to solve it only after i payed attention to gradle's warning. it said  that: Gradle DSL method not found: `сompile()`.
I still couldn't believe that something is wrong with 'compile' so i changed quickblox url to another url  that worked for me. and still got the warning. so i understood that it is not relevant to quickblox url. then when i wrote compile by myself and pasted the url it worked. figuring out that 'c' has wrong ascii was just to satisfy my curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a result of wrong Gradle version.

There is used the following versions:

- 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0' for Gradle Android plugin
- gradleVersion = '2.4' for Gradle

https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: How to change the gradle version? Do I just add this: task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.4'
}

Comment: Still error... A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method ?ompile() for arguments [com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:2.5@aar] on project ':app'.

Comment: By the way, is both my gradle.build have correct format?

Comment: @BillyChrisnawanAdhyaksa i have the same problem. Were you able to fix it.

Comment: @NorrisBoateng Still can't fix it, I start over from my last backup which still works.

Comment: @NorrisBoateng you are too can try my solution.